# Extending Marionette view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In my application, I found it handy to implement a `FrameView` that would extend `LayoutView` but would have some additional logic for keeping frame title etc. (my goal is to let `Region`s deal with displaying the title).

From the Java's Swing perspective, `LayoutView` is a `JPanel` for me, but I would like to turn it to a `JFrame` wannabe :-)

Is there a way to extend the Marionette view (and perform some initialization) in such a way, that the `initialize` method remains unused? (I don't want to bother user with calling `FrameView.prototype.initialize` method to make the things work)

This is my attempt (but it suffers from the problem mentioned above):

```
var FrameView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    if(!this.title) this.title = null;
  },
  setTitle: function(title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.trigger("change:title", title);
  }
})
```

Ideally the `FrameView` would combine `LayoutView` with `Backbone.Model` (so I would get those methods like `setTitle` for granted, even though with slightly different syntax). The `Backbone.Model` part of the view would than keep things like title, icon, whatever.

I am still learning both Backbone.js and Marionette, so my way of thinking might be odd. I would be thankful for both your answers and for any recommendation how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want a default `title` key on your view object, then extend your view prototype with the key:

```
var FrameView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  title: null,
  setTitle: function(title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.trigger("change:title", title);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you - it's that easy! :-) The only "drawback" for me is that I would either have to implement every field (title, icon, ...) by hand, or implement `Backbone.Model`-like functionality on my own (which I am not happy with as I would rather reuse what has been already done). Is there a way to mix `Backbone.Model` in the class, so that I wouldn't have to care about individual fields (and achieve greater generalization)?

Comment: Why won't you use `Backbone.Model` in the first place with your view?
`var FrameModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ defaults: {} /*etc*/ });`  
`var frameView = new FrameView({ model: new FrameModel() });`  
`/*use your model*/ frameView.model.set({title: 'Hey'});`

Comment: This would fail for design purposes. I want `FrameView` to be usable just as a `LayoutView` - just with some additional features. Defining the model explicitly when instantiating the view would mean that user would have to specify some artificial model everytime, which breaks the requirement of having `LayoutView`'s API. (Moreover it would introduce problems when user wants to provide his model for the view.)

Comment: It's hard to guess your design purposes. From my experience you would simply define some kind of a component that would include all required views and models, with a single point of initialization for the end user.